# How to do a 3d rotation to a 2d point in JavaScript (Azure Face Rotation)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, azure, math, formula

I am using the Azure Face API to get the landmarks and rotation angle of a given face. The problem is that all of those points are 2d objects, and I need to rotate them in a 2d space using the yaw, roll and pitch angles of the face.

I have tried to rotate them in the roll angle using this function:

```
  const rotatePoint = (pivotPoint, point, angle) => {
    const { x: px, y: py } = pivotPoint;
    const { x, y } = point;

    var radians = (Math.PI / 180) * angle,
      cos = Math.cos(radians),
      sin = Math.sin(radians),
      nx = cos * (x - px) + sin * (y - py) + px,
      ny = cos * (y - py) - sin * (x - px) + py;

    return { x: nx, y: ny };
  };
```

Using the center of the FaceRectangle (here you can see it: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/cognitive-services/face/images/face.detection.jpg) as pivot point. But I think that the pivot point will only work with a roll rotation. Just imagine a 3d object which is rotated in 3d dimensions. If you have the vertices of this object in a 2d plane, to fully remove the rotation you will need to rotate it in the 3 angles. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Is there any formula to rotate the 2d points in the 3 angles?

Comment: I find your question baffling (perhaps because I am unfamiliar with azure). Rotating a point in 2d requires a pivot point and an angle, not three angles. What are you actually trying to do? What makes you think that the solution you posted doesn't work? How will you know when a solution works?

Comment: The pivot point will only works with a roll rotation (I think). Just imagine a 3d object which is rotated in 3d dimensions. If you have the vertices of this object in a 2d plane, to fully remove the rotation you will need to rotate it in the 3 angles. Just like in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography_(computer_vision)